# PrettyFaces changes the scheme from Https to Http

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

I'm using PrettyFaces in my project. We recently started using SSL (Https), however, when calling, for example ***pretty:main-page*** in a commandlink the https protocol is modified to http. If I used a normal call without pretty: the protocol is not modified.

Comment: Don't you think it is relevant to post the prettyfaces configuratie and version and other infrastructurele info (like regeerde proces)

Comment: The answer of PrettyFaces leader was:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/257#issuecomment-355737351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of PrettyFaces leader was:

"AFAIK there are basically two ways to work around this issue:

You could configure Glassfish to assume the https scheme for the http listeners. AFAIK there is a scheme property on the http listener in the latest Glassfish version. See this issue for details.
If you are using a load balances / reverse proxy, you could rewrite the Location header before sending it back to the requesting client. That should be easy but depends on you load balances setup. If you are using mod_proxy, you can use the ProxyPassReverse command to achieve this."

[github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/257#issuecomment-355737351](http://github.com/ocpsoft/rewrite/issues/257#issuecomment-355737351)

OK!

Comment: Please post a summary here to (otherwise you stand a chance the answer is removed because it is a 'link only' answer which is not good practice according to SO 'guidelines'..